# Loop through Generic List in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In my VB.net application I am populating my customer object and looping through it as shown below.

As there are thousands of customers, I want to do it 500 customers at a time.

Is there anyway I can have one more For loop to process 500 customers at one shot in vB.net

I am not using LinQ as the database is Oracle.

is there anything like

Thanks

```
Dim customerList as new List(of customer)
Dim Customer as new Customer

Try
CustomerList=dataAccess.GetAllCustomers()

if not CustomerList is nothing then

   For each Customer in CustomerList
       BuildXML(custmer.Name,Customer.age,Customer.city)
   next
       ProcessXMLWS(strxml)
end if

Catch ex as exception
   LogError(ex.message)
End try
```

Comment: You mean something like paging?

Comment: If all you are doing is processing one row at a time, what purpose is served by doing it in 500 rows chunks? Surely it would be easier to just do all rows in one loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can loop through blocks of 500 `Customer` objects like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CustomerList.Count Step 500
    'Do things
Next
```

However, it won't do you any good.
Your code is using each `Customer` object individually, so there is nothing you can do with 500 at a time.

**EDIT**:

If you mean that you only want to process the first 500 `Customer` objects, try this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(500, CustomerList.Count)
    Set Customer = CustomerList(i)

    BuildXML(custmer.Name, Customer.age, Customer.city)
Next
```

---

As an aside, you shouldn't write `Dim Customer As New Customer` - by adding the `New` keyword, you create an extra `Customer` instance that you never use.  Instead, write `Dim Customer As Customer` to declare the variable without creating a new `Customer` instance.

Also, you can use VB's `IsNot` keyword in the If statement, like this:

```
If CustomerList IsNot Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 3):

Use counter variable.

```
Dim counter as Integer = 1
For each Customer in CustomerList
   If counter = 500 Then
       ProcessXMLWS(strxml)
       strxml="" '//Empty if any.'
       counter = 1
   Next
   BuildXML(custmer.Name, Customer.age, Customer.city)   
   counter += 1
next
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx

Comment: Thanks adatapost. I don't want to exit just after 500. I want to continue for each 500 records

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim lsItems As Generic.List(Of ClassName) = obj.GetAllItems()
  For i = 0 To lsItems.Count - 1
      'doThings with
      'lsItems(i)
  Next
```